# unable to create row in angular datatable plugin because json parse is not able

Tags: angularjs

in my controller is written as below

```
     .controller('RegionController', function( $scope , regionService,DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {

    var regionDetail = regionService.getRegionDetails();
    regionDetail.then( function ( response )
    {
    $scope.RegionData = response.data;
    });

   var jsondata = JSON.stringify($scope.RegionData);

        $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource(jsondata)
            .withDOM("<'row'<'col-sm-4'l><'col-sm-4 text-center'B><'col-sm-4'f>>tp")
            .withButtons([
                {extend: 'copy',className: 'btn-sm'},
                {extend: 'csv',title: 'ExampleFile', className: 'btn-sm'},
                {extend: 'pdf', title: 'ExampleFile', className: 'btn-sm'},
                {extend: 'print',className: 'btn-sm'}
            ]);


     $scope.dtColumns =
     [
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('region_id').withTitle('Region ID'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('region_name').withTitle('Region Name'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('region_code').withTitle('Region Code'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('created_by').withTitle('Created By')

     ];
```

and my service is written as

```
    regionFactory.getRegionDetails = function() {
        return $http.get('/api/getRegion').then(function (data) {
            //console.log(data);
            return data;
        });
    }
```

and in my html code is to be written is like this

```
    <div class="table-responsive">
              <table datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"></table>
        </div>
```

actual problem is if I pass json format of file then it will show table if I am calling an API then they showing "Loading...." text.
if I am passing response.data (actually is in array format) then they will display no data found

Comment: Ask yourself these questions: what does AJAX mean, especially the first A? Why does a service doing a http call doesn't return the response, and instead returns a promise of a response? When is `$scope.RegionData = response.data;` being executed? When is `var jsondata = JSON.stringify($scope.RegionData);` being executed?

Comment: sorry about that i upload wrong code.

Comment: now i am edit  write code steps are to be given as

Comment: All my questions still stand. Have you thought about them? What are your answers?

Comment: now i am edit  write code steps are to be given as                                        1. they call region service to get all region details. line of code is written as "var regionDetail = regionService.getRegionDetails();"                                  2. and after calling service i am geeting data with "Then" Keyword so they will gat me API Data in Array list.                                                       3. now I add Varriable "var jsondata =JSON.stringify ( $scope.RegionData ) ; " to convert array of data into json format.

Comment: 4. and then we put all data into   " $scope.dtOptions  = 
 DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource( jsondata ) " but it will give me undefined for "jsondata ". so value dtOptions is called before data is arrived in above "$scope.RegionData"

Comment: No, that's not the right chronology. Think about my questions again, and verify your assumptions by adding console.log() calls in the code. Then you'll see what is executed when.